How to translate this missing verb in Tolstoi's original text
I'm reading Hadji Murat, chapter XIII (13).
In the original text, we have:

«один негодяй на...л на меня»

I have the feeling Tolstoi was being very 'realistic' when it comes to dialogue and character situations.
The french 'translation' goes for a more polite expression:

«Un lâche m'avait souillé (...)»


What was the verb that Tolstoi originally intended to use, but didn't write it completely?

I tried to look for variations of urinating or defecating, but I could not find a matching verb. So, I'm starting to wonder whether it's more of a sexual nature, possibly related to rape...
Any help would be appreciated.

I realize that you already have your answer, but can you please add more context to the question for the sake of the future visitors: the name of the work you're citing and several phrases before and after the sentence you're quoting? Thank you in advance!

What fits is either "нассал" or "наблевал", which would be pissed or vomited on me, respectively. Perhaps the French translator also wasn't sure and decided not to specify.

Thanks for the answer ;)

BTW, "насрал" or "наплевал" would also fit the pattern. Maybe it's even a deliberate literary trick by Tolstoi to allow readers to fill in the gap themselves in their imagination depending on how well-mannered they are.
